# Spouse and me applying from different country for US visa

Tags: visas, usa, b1-b2-visas, applications, spouses

We are a couple living in different countries and are planning to visit the US. It’s not clear anywhere in the form where we can state that we will be in the US together apart from the travel companion page. But that seems to be only for people who are traveling together from the beginning whereas we will fly from different countries.

Any advice on the form or the process?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### You Must Submit Separate DS-160 Applications

In general, when applying for a US visa, [each traveller must submit a separate DS-160 application form](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/tourism-visit/visitor.html). In your case, you are applying from different countries, which means that you will attend interviews in different countries, so it makes sense to fill in separate applications.

#### Companions or Not?

You state you are flying in from separate countries. This indicates that you are not really travelling together. However, what really matters is whether or not you go through immigration checks together.

Will you be meeting your spouse after the immigration checks, once you are officially on US soil? If so, you are not travel companions.

Will you be going through US immigration together? If yes then you are travel companions and should add this information in your application forms.